# Middleware monad?

Tags: functional-programming, monads, algebraic-data-types

I'm newbye experimenting functional programming in Javascript.

I'm learning and using monads (Reader, State, Fluture ...) to compose my Node apps with pure functions.

But often I feel the need of a data structure, similar to a Monad but where I can chain functions in the middleware.

Think of it as a structure of two function

```
f: a->d
g: d->b
```

Running would be like compose the two function **g(f(x))**

But I want a map like method to add function in the middleware of the 2.

So I could **map(h)(i)(m)**

where

```
h: d -> e
i: e -> d
```

Running the mapped structure I get g(i(h(f(x))))

I have tried to search for a data structure of this king in JS libs or papers and even haskel world but found nothing. I'm missing something? Or there is a more simple way to compose function in a "middleware" fashion without implement a dedicated monad?

Comment: What is `m` in `map(h)(i)(m)`?

Comment: Sure, you can just write a function `map` that does what you want it to do. It doesn't have to be a monad for that.

Comment: `map(h) (i) (m)` should be rather `map(x => h(i(x))) (m)`, where the first argument is an arbirarily complex reverse function composition with type `d -> d`. However, such a composition is stattic, i.e. you cannot skip a function in the middle.

Comment: Could be implemented but would be a good pratice or are there better solutions? An use case for It could be to have a lazy function where I can map the output result but even change the inputs arguments with "middleware" functions. For example a monad for sql query where you can map and work with results and change input argumets in different moments before finally run it.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt less static alternative?

Comment: Nope. More promising would be a recursive list like data structure that holds the functions. As opposed to a normal list you'd cons onto the second element of the list, not its head. Then you could fold the list right associatively and depending on the accumulator skip function calls. The type of such a list would be a bit ugly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to map outputs, that's a covariant functor's `map` function.

If you're wanting to map inputs, that's a contravariant functor's `contramap` function.

If you're wanting to do a change in the middle, you likely have to roll your own, but that doesn't mean you are forced to specify concrete functions in order. If I wanted to be able to specify `h` and `i` from your example at the last minute, I would partially apply a function like:

```js
const query = f => g => h => i => x => g(i(h(f(x))))
const partial = query(f)(g)
// Later on...
const withHAndI = partial(h)(i)
// Even later...
const result = withHAndI(x)
```

There are ways to make something like this more general, but often the simpler the better.